# jQuery - count all Select tags and subtract the length

Tags: jquery

I have `n` select tags in HtML from with same `data-field`. I want to count the number of select tags based on  `data-field="x_RATING"`. i want to return total count by subtracting `1` to the total.

I tried below code, but not returning the count.

```js
var x = $('select[data-field="x_RATING"]').length() - 1;
alert(x);
```

```html
<select data-table="assessment_rating"
        data-field="x_RATING"
        data-value-separator=", "
        id="x5_RATING"
        name="x5_RATING"
        class="form-control">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select data-table="assessment_rating"
        data-field="x_RATING"
        data-value-separator=", "
        id="x7_RATING"
        name="x7_RATING"
        class="form-control">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is happening with your code?

Comment: not returning count from the code which i used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var x = $('select[data-field="x_RATING"]').length-1;
alert(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-table="assessment_rating"
        data-field="x_RATING"
        data-value-separator=", "
        id="x5_RATING"
        name="x5_RATING"
        class="form-control">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<select data-table="assessment_rating"
        data-field="x_RATING"
        data-value-separator=", "
        id="x7_RATING"
        name="x7_RATING"
        class="form-control">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Just remove the `()` in `length` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml xpath query is wrong. Try the following

```
var count = $("//select[@data-field='x_RATING'").length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `.length`

```js
var x = $('select[data-field="x_RATING"]').length - 1;
alert(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-table="assessment_rating" data-field="x_RATING" data-value-separator=", " id="x5_RATING" name="x5_RATING" class="form-control">

<option value="">Please select</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="1">1</option></select>

<select data-table="assessment_rating" data-field="x_RATING" data-value-separator=", " id="x7_RATING" name="x7_RATING" class="form-control">

<option value="">Please select</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="1">1</option></select>
```